# Best practices for distributed tracing in Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, open-telemetry, opentracing

I'm considering distributing tracing in the context of Flink. I have the following questions:

1. How to implement tracing internally within the Flink pipeline itself? That is, how to propagate the tracing context between the different operators from the sources to the sinks (*In-Process Context Propagation*)?
2. How to glue things at the edges? That is, extract the context when reading from the sources and put it when writing to the sinks (*Inter-Process Context Propagation*)?

For 2 in particular I just need to support Kafka sources & sinks. I guess the typical thing would be to use the kafka headers for that, as described [here](https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/reading-apache-kafka-headers-with-apache-flink/). This also has the advantage that it does not require changes in the payload schemas for example.

More generally, are there any (Flink-specific) libraries/integrations available which facilitate the task at hand? E.g., by decorating transformations with tracing capabilities as done [here](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-kafka-client) for Kafka Streams. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875462/opentracing-with-kafka-streams-how-to) or [this interceptor-like wrapper](https://github.com/TouK/nussknacker/blob/cc59e10f1d4771eac52eb0bf43429ec8fcce9526/engine/flink/components-utils/src/main/scala/pl/touk/nussknacker/engine/flink/util/function/ProcessFunctionInterceptor.scala#L9) which could be another option for effectively enlarging the context for tracing purposes.

For what it's worth, I'm mostly interested in solutions based on [OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/) and/or [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/).

Comment: there's no Flink-specific instrumentation that I'm aware of: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md#libraries--frameworks

if you are interested in contributing, check out https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/contributing/writing-instrumentation.md

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I will consider that after instrumenting my jobs, depending on how reusable my solution ends up being.

Comment: @salvalcantara Did you end up implementing your solution?

Comment: No, in the end I added tracing in rather adhoc way...

Answer (score 1):

1. within the process

   - java process to use ThreadLocal to pass
   - Can not invade the queue, framework, components can be wrapped objects, in the wrapped object to pass
2. between processes

   - rest, rpc, mq protocol within the Header pass

   [See trace implementation for more information](https://www.devean.cn/en/blog/2024/distributed-tracing/)